# can't find any wireless network interface on lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, vmware

I have a PC Toshiba satellite notebook with an installed release Lubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04 trusty) kernel 3.13.0-39 generic. After an VmWare installation with Windows 7, I stopped my system forced with shutdown for problems during the installation.

On The reboot my wifi network doesn't work, I lost my wireless network interface.
I see The wifi connection configured but is not possible to connect.

If I run WiFi RutilT tool I receive The message:

> critica error: can't find any wireless network interface. Code -3

With `lspci -i nn|grep -i net` I see:

```
05:00.0 network controller [0280]: Intel corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
```

With `iwconfig` I see:

```
vmnet8 no wireless extension
lo no wireless extension
eth0 no wireless extension
```